# Using MediaSource extensions to play a video playlist

Tags: javascript, html, video, media-source

I am trying to achieve a reliable, gapless video playlist in HTML5/JS. To do this, I want to buffer a dynamic playlist in memory and then send the buffer to an HTML5 video element.

I have a choice in how the videos are encoded, and this only has to work on the Chrome browser, so I'm thinking of using webm videos and MediaSource extensions. The video files will be stored on Amazon S3 and delivered with CloudFront.

I've seen the following example of the MediaSource API. The key difference is that instead of reading chunks of a file, I'm reading in lots of files.
http://bluishcoder.co.nz/2013/08/20/progress-towards-media-source-extensions-in-firefox.html

How can this be adapted to work with multiple files rather than chunks of a file?

Comment: I [answered this before](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14108536/how-do-i-append-two-video-files-data-to-a-source-buffer-using-media-source-api/18026530#18026530), the key part was `source.sourceBuffers[0].timestampOffset = duration`. However, that no longer works in newer versions of Chrome/Firefox. Even [Eric Bidelman's Demo](http://html5-demos.appspot.com/static/media-source.html), which everyone seems to use at first, isn't fully working now.  Do you have any code that works with a single video?  Creating a playlist is tough when I can't even find a basic demo that works any longer.

Comment: I don't have any working code beyond that demo, however the demo that you pointed out does seem to work for me.

Comment: Does the video in that demo actually play the full 6 seconds of the clip?  For me, the video stops at 04.19 in Chrome and 05.08 in Firefox with the mediasource.enabled flag, but it used to go the full 6 seconds.

Comment: Ah, no, you're right. Maybe we should abandon this idea until browsers/stdanards are updated. What are your thoughts?

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately I had to table my mediasource plans.  I have a hacky fallback where I load the second video in a separate `<video>` element set to `display: none`, then toggle display on both and start playing the second when the first finishes.  Good enough for our needs right now, but not ideal because of lack of controls for seeking through the "full video" and possible stuttering between clips on slow devices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We ended up writing this Javascript library to handle video playback:
https://github.com/jameshadley/LifemirrorPlayer/blob/master/LifemirrorPlayer.js

It doesn't use the MediaSourceAPI but it works surprisingly well.