# Receiving a video parts and append them to a MediaSource using javascript

Tags: javascript, video

I'm making a video streaming service and I'm having trouble recreating the source stream on the client.

I have made a camera page that sends video data chunks to the server along with a video index, the server then stores this data chunk on the harddisk for the client to download. I can retrieve the video data chunk from the client by calling the url:

```
/Lessen/LesStreamPart/{streamid}?Index={index}
```

**Explanation:**

```
hub.server.join(current_lesid);
```

When a client joins the stream the page will start to receive updates about the stream by SignalR:

```
hub.client.updateLesStream = function (lesid, lesstreamid, contenttype, index, duration)
```

When a update is received, the page checks if it has already setup the MediaSource control for that stream, if not, because it is the first time, the page will start the stream:

```
function startStream()
```

When the stream is started the page will setup the MediaSource object for the video element. Then wait till the MediaSource object is instantiated.

```
function openStream()
```

After the MediaSource object has been instantiated the page will start populating the MediaSource object with the Mimetype information, after that it will load the first part of the video stream and will append it to the MediaSource object.

```
function loadChunks()
```

Once the MediaSource update has finished, the page will start loading the remaining video parts.

```
hub.client.updateLesStream = function (lesid, lesstreamid, contenttype, index, duration)
```

When the camera adds a new chunk, the page will be signalled again using SignalR. Because the streamid will match the page will then continue with loading the newer chunks by calling:

```
function loadChunks()
```

**JS:**

```
// Declare variables
var hub = $.connection.lesHub; // The SignalR hub

var buffering = false; // Semaphore for buffering
var video; // Pointer to video element
var mediaSource; // Pointer to mediasource object
var sourceBuffer; // Pointer to mediasource' sourcebuffer object

var current_lesid = document.querySelector('#LesId').value; // Current les id
var current_lesstreamid; // Current stream id (set in update)
var current_contenttype; // Current video content type (mimetype)
var current_index; // Current loaded index
var current_indexlength; // Current loaded index length    

// Will be called once SignalR sends a video chunk update event
function startStream() {

    // Open MediaSource
    mediaSource = new MediaSource();

    // Add listeners
    mediaSource.addEventListener('webkitsourceopen', openStream, false);
    //mediaSource.addEventListener('webkitsourceclose', closed, false);
    mediaSource.addEventListener('sourceopen', openStream, false);
    //mediaSource.addEventListener('sourceclose', closed, false);

    // Set MediaSource as video element source
    video = document.querySelector('video#VideoPlayerElement');
    video.src = URL.createObjectURL(mediaSource);

}
function openStream() {

    // Set the buffering semafore
    buffering = true;

    // Start the stream with contenttype
    sourceBuffer = mediaSource.addSourceBuffer(current_contenttype);

    // If there are any video chunks
    if (current_indexlength > 0) {

        // Load the first video chunk
        var url = "/Lessen/LesStreamPart/" + current_lesstreamid +"?Index=0";
        var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
        req.responseType = "arraybuffer";
        req.open("GET", url, true);
        req.onload = function () {

            // Append response to the sourcebuffer
            var resp = req.response;
            var array = new Uint8Array(resp);
            sourceBuffer.appendBuffer(array);

            // Set the current index to 0
            current_index = 0;

            // Wait for the sourcebuffer to be ready to load all other chunks
            sourceBuffer.addEventListener("updateend", loadChunks);

        }
        req.send();

    }
    else {

        // Release buffering semafore
        buffering = false;

    }
}
function loadChunks() {

    // Set the buffering semafore
    buffering = true;        

    // Calculate the newindex
    var newindex = current_index + 1;

    // Check if the newindex is in use?
    if (newindex < current_indexlength)
    {
        // Load new video chunk
        var url = "/Lessen/LesStreamPart/" + current_lesstreamid + "?Index=" + newindex;
        var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
        req.responseType = "arraybuffer";
        req.open("GET", url, true);
        req.onload = function () {

            // Append response to the sourcebuffer
            var resp = req.response;
            var array = new Uint8Array(resp);
            sourceBuffer.appendBuffer(array);

            // Set the current index to newindex
            current_index = newindex;

            // Recursive call to add remaining chunks
            loadChunks();

        }
        req.send();

    }
    else {

        // Newindex is not in use, release buffering semafore
        buffering = false;

    }

}


// Start recording callbacks
hub.client.startLesStream = function (lesid, lesstreamid, contenttype) {

    // This is called while there are no video data chunks, so we can ignore it.

};

// Update recording callbacks
hub.client.updateLesStream = function (lesid, lesstreamid, contenttype, index, duration) {

    // Check if update is for our lesid (not actually needed)
    if (current_lesid == lesid) {

        // Check if buffering
        if (buffering) {

            // The webpage is currently busy, we will time out this message with 100ms
            setTimeout(function () {
                hub.client.updateLesStream(lesid, lesstreamid, contenttype, index, duration);
            }, 100);

        }
        else {

            // Not buffering, so we can begin processing
            // When the streamid is different reload the stream, when the page starts 
            // the "current_lesstreamid" is undefined, so we will reload the video
            if (current_lesstreamid == lesstreamid) {

                // Update to current stream
                current_indexlength = index + 1;
                loadChunks();

            }
            else {

                // Different stream started
                current_lesstreamid = lesstreamid;
                current_contenttype = contenttype;
                current_indexlength = index + 1;
                startStream();

            }

        }

    }

};

// Stop recording callbacks
hub.client.stopLesStream = function (lesid, lesstreamid, contenttype) {

    // Check if update is for our lesid (not actually needed)
    if (current_lesid == lesid) {

        // Check if stream is currently shown
        if (current_lesstreamid == lesstreamid) {

            // Stop the stream
            mediaSource.endOfStream();

        }

    }

};


// Start SignalR
$.connection.hub.start().done(function () {

    // And join the room
    hub.server.join(current_lesid);

});
```

**HTML:**

```
<input type="hidden" id="LesId" value="@(Model.Id)" />
<video autoplay controls id="VideoPlayerElement"></video>
```

**OUTPUT:**

[image: Broken video controls]

The page doesn't show any errors, but I do get a broken video icon in the video element. Does anyone know what this might be?

I read in a different stackoverflow that it might be the VP8 codec that needs to be used, I changed it, but it remains not working.

EDIT:

I changed the javascript code a bit. It turned out I called the "loadChunks" function, but it was already called by the "updateend" event of the "sourceBuffer". I then got a lot more errors.

I changed the way I communicate with the server to "$.get();". It solved the errors, but I still get no image.

```
// Declare variables
var hub = $.connection.lesHub; // The SignalR hub

var buffering = false; // Semaphore for buffering
var video; // Pointer to video element
var mediaSource; // Pointer to mediasource object
var sourceBuffer; // Pointer to mediasource' sourcebuffer object

var current_lesid = document.querySelector('#LesId').value; // Current les id
var current_lesstreamid; // Current stream id (set in update)
var current_contenttype; // Current video content type (mimetype)
var current_index; // Current loaded index
var current_indexlength; // Current loaded index length    

// Will be called once SignalR sends a video chunk update event
function startStream() {

    // Open MediaSource
    mediaSource = new MediaSource();

    // Add listeners
    mediaSource.addEventListener('webkitsourceopen', openStream, false);
    //mediaSource.addEventListener('webkitsourceclose', closed, false);
    mediaSource.addEventListener('sourceopen', openStream, false);
    //mediaSource.addEventListener('sourceclose', closed, false);

    // Set MediaSource as video element source
    video = document.querySelector('video#VideoPlayerElement');
    video.src = URL.createObjectURL(mediaSource);

}
function openStream() {

    // Set the buffering semafore
    buffering = true;

    // Start the stream with contenttype
    sourceBuffer = mediaSource.addSourceBuffer(current_contenttype);

    // Wait for the sourcebuffer to be ready to load all other chunks
    sourceBuffer.addEventListener("updateend", loadChunks);

    // If there are any video chunks
    if (current_indexlength > 0) {

        // Load the first video chunk
        var url = "/Lessen/LesStreamPart/" + current_lesstreamid + "?Index=0";

        //$("body").append("<video><source src='" + url + "'/></video>");

        $.get(url, function (resp) {

            //var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
            //req.responseType = "arraybuffer";
            //req.open("GET", url, true);
            //req.onload = function () {

            // Append response to the sourcebuffer
            //var resp = req.response;
            var array = new Uint8Array(resp);
            sourceBuffer.appendBuffer(array);

            // Set the current index to 0
            current_index = 0;

            //}
            //req.send();

        });
    }
    else {

        // Release buffering semafore
        buffering = false;

    }
}
function loadChunks() {

    //video.play();

    // Set the buffering semafore
    buffering = true;        

    // Calculate the newindex
    var newindex = current_index + 1;

    // Check if the newindex is in use?
    if (newindex < current_indexlength) {
        // Load new video chunk
        var url = "/Lessen/LesStreamPart/" + current_lesstreamid + "?Index=" + newindex;

        $.get(url, function (resp) {

            //var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
            //req.responseType = "arraybuffer";
            //req.open("GET", url, true);
            //req.onload = function () {

            // Append response to the sourcebuffer
            //var resp = req.response;
            var array = new Uint8Array(resp);
            sourceBuffer.appendBuffer(array);

            // Set the current index to newindex
            current_index = newindex;

            //}
            //req.send();

        });
    }
    else {

        // Newindex is not in use, release buffering semafore
        buffering = false;

    }

}


// Start recording callbacks
hub.client.startLesStream = function (lesid, lesstreamid, contenttype) {

    // This is called while there are no video data chunks, so we can ignore it.

};

// Update recording callbacks
hub.client.updateLesStream = function (lesid, lesstreamid, contenttype, index, duration) {

    // Check if update is for our lesid (not actually needed)
    if (current_lesid == lesid) {

        // Check if buffering
        if (buffering) {

            // The webpage is currently busy, we will time out this message with 100ms
            setTimeout(function () {
                hub.client.updateLesStream(lesid, lesstreamid, contenttype, index, duration);
            }, 100);

        }
        else {

            // Not buffering, so we can begin processing
            // When the streamid is different reload the stream, when the page starts 
            // the "current_lesstreamid" is undefined, so we will reload the video
            if (current_lesstreamid == lesstreamid) {

                // Update to current stream
                current_indexlength = index + 1;
                loadChunks();

            }
            else {

                // Different stream started
                current_lesstreamid = lesstreamid;
                current_contenttype = contenttype;
                current_indexlength = index + 1;
                startStream();

            }

        }

    }

};

// Stop recording callbacks
hub.client.stopLesStream = function (lesid, lesstreamid, contenttype) {

    // Check if update is for our lesid (not actually needed)
    if (current_lesid == lesid) {

        // Check if stream is currently shown
        if (current_lesstreamid == lesstreamid) {

            // Stop the stream
            mediaSource.endOfStream();

        }

    }

};


// Start SignalR
$.connection.hub.start().done(function () {

    // And join the room
    hub.server.join(current_lesid);

});
```

Comment: What is the format of the chunks? are you prepending the initlisation fragment?

Comment: @szatmary the format is now: "video/webm;codecs=vp8". I use a MediaRecorder object on the camera page that splits the output into chunks of 500ms video data. When the MediaRecorder fires a "ondataavailable" event I simply save the data to the server. When I merge all files together on the server I can see the recorded video, so the data seems to be ok.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to be a codec issue and the method for reading data. When you receive a video blob, you need to convert/store it using a FileReader, this worked for me. For best codec support I needed to use the VP8 codec (please inform me if you know a better one).

This is my working example where I use a MediaRecorder to record the webcam then paste the video blobs into a MediaSource.

```js
const video1 = document.getElementById('video1');
        const video2 = document.getElementById('video2');

        const mediaSource = new MediaSource();
        video2.src = URL.createObjectURL(mediaSource);
        mediaSource.addEventListener('sourceopen', sourceOpen);

        function sourceOpen(openargs) {
            navigator.mediaDevices
                .getUserMedia({ audio: false, video: true })
                .then(function (stream) {
                    video1.srcObject = stream;

                    var options = { mimeType: 'video/webm; codecs=vp8' };
                    var mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(stream, options);
                    var sourceBuffer = null;

                    mediaRecorder.ondataavailable = function (e) {
                        if (sourceBuffer == null) {
                            sourceBuffer = mediaSource.addSourceBuffer(mediaRecorder.mimeType);
                            window.sourceBuffer = sourceBuffer;
                        }
                        var reader = new FileReader();
                        reader.addEventListener("loadend", function () {
                            var arr = new Uint8Array(reader.result);
                            sourceBuffer.appendBuffer(arr);
                        });
                        reader.readAsArrayBuffer(e.data);
                    };
                    mediaRecorder.start(5000);
                });
        }
```

```css
        video {
            width: 320px;
            height: 180px;
        }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>

    <video id="video1" controls autoplay muted></video><br />
    <video id="video2" controls autoplay muted></video>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for sharing your solution! I have noticed that if you randomly drop some data from MediaRecorder, it breaks. Do you have any idea how to avoid that?

Comment: I ended up abandining this whole concept

Answer (score 2):

I get perfect example to solve this problem and into simple way...

i am using three static files, but you can append data from socket's or any api also.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>
  <br>
  <video controls="true" autoplay="true"></video>

  <script>
    (async() => {


      const mediaSource = new MediaSource();

      const video = document.querySelector("video");

      // video.oncanplay = e => video.play();

      const urls = ["https://nickdesaulniers.github.io/netfix/demo/frag_bunny.mp4", "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/w3c/web-platform-tests/master/media-source/mp4/test.mp4","https://nickdesaulniers.github.io/netfix/demo/frag_bunny.mp4"];

      const request = url => fetch(url).then(response => response.arrayBuffer());

      // `urls.reverse()` stops at `.currentTime` : `9`
      const files = await Promise.all(urls.map(request));

      /*
       `.webm` files
       Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'appendBuffer' on 'SourceBuffer': This SourceBuffer has been removed from the parent media source.
       Uncaught DOMException: Failed to set the 'timestampOffset' property on 'SourceBuffer': This SourceBuffer has been removed from the parent media source.
      */
      // const mimeCodec = "video/webm; codecs=opus";
      // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14108536/how-do-i-append-two-video-files-data-to-a-source-buffer-using-media-source-api/
      const mimeCodec = "video/mp4; codecs=avc1.42E01E, mp4a.40.2";


      const media = await Promise.all(files.map(file => {
        return new Promise(resolve => {
          let media = document.createElement("video");
          let blobURL = URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([file]));
          media.onloadedmetadata = async e => {
            resolve({
              mediaDuration: media.duration,
              mediaBuffer: file
            })
          }
          media.src = blobURL;
        })
      }));

      console.log(media);

      mediaSource.addEventListener("sourceopen", sourceOpen);

      video.src = URL.createObjectURL(mediaSource);

      async function sourceOpen(event) {

        if (MediaSource.isTypeSupported(mimeCodec)) {
          const sourceBuffer = mediaSource.addSourceBuffer(mimeCodec);

          for (let chunk of media) {
            await new Promise(resolve => {
              sourceBuffer.appendBuffer(chunk.mediaBuffer);
              sourceBuffer.onupdateend = e => {
                sourceBuffer.onupdateend = null;
                sourceBuffer.timestampOffset += chunk.mediaDuration;
                console.log(mediaSource.duration);
                resolve()
              }
            })

          }

          mediaSource.endOfStream();

        }  
        else {
          console.warn(mimeCodec + " not supported");
        }
      };

    })()
  </script>


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it didn't work for me at first and I got catch up in the search for a solution so I didn't reply. This was because you are using a <video> element to load the video data into the page, this doesn't work for me as the videoparts are always headerless so doesn't load into a video element. The solution was to use a FileReader instead.